# Plane in parameter form to affin form.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have the plane

$$\pi : \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x & = & -2-3s+t \\
    y & = & 1-2s-t \\
    z & = & 3-t
  \end{array}
\right.$$

and I want to write it on the form $ax+by+cz+d.$ The book does Gauss elimination, but I can't follow. They proceed by this:

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    2s-t & = & x+1 \\
    3s+t & = & y \\
    s+t  & = & z-2
  \end{array}
\right.\Longleftrightarrow\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    2s-t & = & x+1 \\
    5t & = & -3x+2y-3 \\
    -3t  & = & x-2z+5
  \end{array}
\right.$$

and finally

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    2s-t & = & x+1 \\
    5t & = & -3x+2y-3 \\
    0  & = & -4x+6y-10z+16
  \end{array}
\right.$$

The RHS in the last equation is the equation for the plane. What happened in the Gauss elimination steps? How did $3s+t$ become $5t$ and how did $y$ become $-3x+2y-3?$

Why does the last equation represent the equation of the plane? Is it clear and intuitive? How?

I have the crappiest book ever.

Comment: 1. You can do Gauss elimination yourself and (if both you and the book is correct) get the same result. 2. The equation of the plane is an equation over $x, y, z$ variables that is correct for all points on the plane. If from the parametric form and can transform it into that form (equation over $x, y, z$ variables) then it must be an equation of the plane.

Comment: 1. I don't understand the arithmetic behind their way, as I said, how did $3s+t$ become $5t$?. And no, one does not always get the same answer with Gauss elimination, an equation can have infinite solutions of different parametric forms. 2. We only got the desired form on the last equation, what geometric sginificance does row 1 and 2 have then? Wh are they even there if they don't represent anything?

Comment: Row 1 and 2 represent that particular parametrization. For different parametrization we will get different "row 1 and 2", but the same plane equation (up to a scalar multiplication). | The particular way how Gaussian elimination is done is not very important in this case, just need to know that the book use Gaussian elimination to "eliminate" variable $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:$$5t=2(3s+t)-3(2s-t)=2y-3(x+1)=2y-3x-3=-3x+2y-3$$

Answer (score 1):

Look at the problem from another side.

A point $P=(x,y,z)$ in on the plane if 
$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x & = & -2-3s+t \\
    y & = & 1-2s-t \\
    z & = & 3-t
  \end{array} \qquad (1)
\right.$$

from the third equation we have: $t=3-z$ . Substituting in the second we find $s=-1-\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}z$ and substituting all in the first we find:
$$
x=4+\frac{3}{2}y-\frac{5}{2}z \quad \iff \quad 2x-3y+5z=8
$$

So the coordinates of $P$ satistie this equation taht is the equation of the plane .

The Gauss elimination is only a different algebraic procedure to solve the system (1) and the equation that you have found is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse-engineer the specific steps that the book used by examining the right-hand sides of the equations. Take, for example, the transformation $3s+t=y\Longleftrightarrow 5t=-3x+2y-3$. The variable $x$ only appears on the first line of the first set of equations and the variable $y$ only appears on the second. So, the new second equation must be $2$ times the old second one minus $3$ times the first old one. Sure enough, $2(3s+t)-3(2s-t)=2y-3(x+1)$ simplifies to $5t=-3x+2y-3$. In the same way, we can see that $-3t=x-2z+5$ is obtained by subtracting $2$ times the third equation from the first.

For the final step, the $t$ in the last equation needs to be eliminated. Looking at the coefficients of $t$ on the second and third lines, an obvious way to do this is to add $3$ times the second equation to $5$ times the third, which appears to be what was done here.

At each stage of this process you have a set of equations that are satisfied by all points on the plane. This of course includes the last equation. That one doesn’t involve $s$ or $t$ and so is an implicit Cartesian equation of the plane.